# Passing a named parameter in MVC via Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning MVC and I can't work out how to pass a parameter by name to a form.

Given the following bit of code:

```
 string itemID = item.ID.ToString();
   <li>@Html.ActionLink((string)item.Title, "StartRun", "Run",new { id = itemID}, null)</li>
```

I'd expected to be able to retrieve the parameter on the receiving controller and pass it to the view by doing something like:

```
ViewBag.ID = Request["id"];
```

This doesn't retrieve anything and when I work through the Request[] array I can't find the value. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Run controller, just do the following:

```
public ActionResult StartRun(string id)
{
    ViewBag.ID = id;
}
```

Your return value might be a bit different, but that's fine. If you want `id` to be optional, make it an optional parameter:

```
public ActionResult StartRun(string id = "5")
{
    ViewBag.ID = id;
}
```

You can also use an `int` instead if you know your ID will always be an `int`:

```
public ActionResult StartRun(int id)
{
    ViewBag.ID = id;
}
```

Comment: Marvellous, thanks. I've a lot to get done today and I can't find the book I'd bought to learn it all from and your post has been a great help.